# How to use execvp() to execute a command

Tags: c, shell

So I'm trying to create a custom shell for my school project. My method was to create child process, and have that process execute the command using the execvp() function that my professor briefly mentioned in class that we are meant to use. Here's my code, as always, any help is appreciated.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/types.h>

#define MAX_LINE 80



int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    char *input = (char*)malloc(MAX_LINE*sizeof(char)); 
    int should_run = 1;

    while(should_run){
        printf("osh>");
        fflush(stdout);

        pid_t pid;
        pid = fork();
        if(pid < 0){
            printf("error with creating chiled process");
            return 0;
        }

        if(pid == 0){
            fgets(input, MAX_LINE, stdin);
            char *token = strtok(input," ");

            if(execvp(token[0], token) < 0){
                printf("Error in execution.");
                return(0);
            }
            //should_run = 0;
        }
        waitpid(pid, 1, 0);

    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Did you check the **9** results that come back from the search **"custom shell school project"** already on this site?

Comment: when calling any of the heap allocation functions ( `malloc` `calloc` `realloc` ) 1) always check (!=NULL) the returned value to assure the operation was successful.  2) the returned type is `void*`, which can be assigned to any other pointer,.. Casting just clutters the code.  3) the expression: `sizeof(char)` is defined in the C standard as 1.  Multiplying anything by 1 has no effect and just clutter the code.  Suggest remove the case, remove the expression, add checking of the returned value.

Comment: when calling `strtok()`, always check (!=NULL) the returned value to assure the operation was successful.

Comment: 1( the function: `execvp()` only returns if it failed, so no need for the '`if()` syntax.  2)  regarding: `printf("Error in execution.");`  Error messages should be output to `stderr`, not `stdout` and should also output the reason the system thinks the error occurred suggest calling `perror( "...failed" ); 3) Note: a returned value of `0` *typically` means success.  Suggest using `exit( EXIT_FAILURE );` when exiting due to a failure

Answer (score 2):

The prototype of `execvp` is

```
int execvp(const char *file, char *const argv[]);
```

It expects a pointer to `char` as the first argument, and a `NULL`-terminated
pointer to an array of `char*`. You are passing completely wrong arguments.

You are passing a single `char` as first argument and a `char*` as the second.

Use `execlp` instead:

```
int execlp(const char *file, const char *arg, ...
              /* (char  *) NULL */);
```

So

```
char *token = strtok(input," \n");

if(token == NULL)
{
    fprintf(stderr, "only delimiters in line\n");
    exit(1);
}

if(execlp(token, token, NULL) < 0){
    fprintf(stderr, "Error in execution: %s\n", strerror(errno));
    exit(1);
}
```

Also the convention in UNIX is to print error messages to `stderr` and a process with an error should
have an exit status other than 0.

Answer (score 1):

As Pablo's states, you are passing the wrong arguments to `execvp()`. 
You can consider coding by yourself a function (`char **strsplit(char *str, char delim)`) which takes a string and split it into smaller pieces, returning an array of strings.

Also don't ignore compiler's warnings, they tell you a lot of things, and I suggest you to compile with `gcc -Wall -Wextra -Werror` to get almost any possible error in your program.

I tell you this because `waitpid()` takes as second argument a pointer to integer, to get an update of the status of the forked program. With this status you how the program exited (normally, segf, bus error...), you can use it to print an error if something went wrong.

You can consider using `execv()` instead (I know I'm going off topic, but you can learn useful things doing this), and find by yourself the correct executable(s).

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <dirent.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>

#define MAX_LINE 255

char    **strsplit(char *str, char delim);
char    *strjoin(char const *s1, char const *s2);


int         isexec(char *path)
{
    struct stat buf;

    lstat(path, &buf);
    if (S_ISREG(buf.st_mode) && (S_IXUSR & buf.st_mode))
        return (1);
    return (0);
}

static char     *find_exec_readdir(char *paths, char *cmd)
{
    DIR             *dir;
    struct dirent   *dirent;
    char            *exec;

    exec = NULL;
    if ((dir = opendir(paths)) != NULL)
    {
        while ((dirent = readdir(dir)) != NULL)
        {
            if (!strcmp(dirent->d_name, cmd))
            {
                exec = strdup(dirent->d_name);
                break ;
            }
        }
        if (closedir(dir))
            dprintf(2, "Failed closing dir.\n");
    }
    return (exec);
}

char    *find_exec(char *cmd, char **paths)
{
    char            *exec;
    char            *path;
    char            *tmp;
    int             i;

    i = -1;
    exec = NULL;
    path = NULL;
    if ((cmd[0] == '.' || cmd[0] == '/'))
    {
        if (isexec(cmd))
            return (strdup(cmd));
        return (NULL);
    }
    while (paths[++i])
        if ((exec = find_exec_readdir(paths[i], cmd)) != NULL)
        {
            tmp = strjoin(paths[i], "/");
            path = strjoin(tmp, exec);
            free(tmp);
            free(exec);
            break ;
        }
    return (path);
}

int handle_return_status(int status)
{
    int         sig;
    int         i;

    if (!WIFEXITED(status) && WIFSIGNALED(status))
    {
        sig = WTERMSIG(status);
        i = -1;
        while (++i <= 13)
        {
            if (print_signal_error(sig))
            {
                return (-1);
            }
        }
        dprintf(2, "Process terminated with unknown signal: %d\n", sig, NULL);
        return (-1);
    }
    return (0);
}


int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    char    *input = NULL; 
    char    **command = NULL;
    int     should_run = 1;
    int     status = 0;


    (void)argc;
    (void)argv;
    if ((input = (char*)malloc(MAX_LINE*sizeof(char))) == NULL)
        return (dprintf(2, "Failed to malloc, abort.\n"));
    while(should_run){
        printf("osh> ");
        fflush(stdout);

        pid_t pid;
        pid = fork();
        if(pid < 0)
            return (dprintf(2, "error with creating chiled process\n"));

        if(pid == 0){
            fgets(input, MAX_LINE, stdin);
            command = strsplit(input, ' ');
            command[0] = find_exec(command[0], strsplit(getenv("PATH"), ':'));

            if(execv(command[0], &command[1]) < 0)
                return (dprintf(2, "Error in execution.\n"));
            //should_run = 0;
        }
        waitpid(pid, &status, 0);
        handle_ret_status(status);

    }
    return 0;
}
```